# Crackly image from my HTPC

Tags: windows-7, htpc, 1080p

I have an odd problem. Whenever my HTPC is left on over night the image starts to crackle. I originally suspected my HDMI lead, but noticed that if I change the resolution and change it back, the problem goes away.

My spec

- 512MB XFX HD 5450
- 3 530 2.93Ghz
- Asus P7H55
- 4gb RAM

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but it only happens occasionally. I have Samsung 37" TV with an XFX card, hooked up via DVI->HDMI so perhaps it's the XFX card that's causing the issue?

I thought perhaps it's something to do with waking up from sleep mode?

I wouldn't say my image is 'crackly' infact guests wouldn't even notice it, however it bugs me! I also have to change the resolution to something else and then back again (note: the resolution never actually changes to cause the problem - mine always remains the same, it just happens that 'refreshing' the resolution solves the problem)

Comment: Mine is very noticeable, reminds me of crackle from old film stock but horizontal. Also, mine seems to go when I play something.